# Android PhoneStateListener.onSignalStrengthsChanged()

Tags: android, kotlin, lte, cellinfo

I'd like to tracking Lte signal strength, so I've been using below method.

[PhoneStateListener.onSignalStrengthsChanged(singnalStrength: SignalStrength)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength))

```
telephonyManager.listen(mListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS)
```

and I've been checking the cell infos by polling `telephonyManager.allCellInfo` every second.

the problem is `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` isn't called although the values from `telephonyManager.allCellInfo` was changed.
`onSignalStrengthsChanged()` is called only sometimes.

when would be `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` called?